# Retiling a mosaic from new coordinates using GDAL

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal-translate, image-mosaic

I am trying to retile a large mosaic tiff that I have created, but re-clip the large tiff using some slightly different coordinates that I have created that allow me to introduce a little bit of overlap between them. I've set the mosaic here to 4326. And my sample test coordiantes to clip are also in 4326. Coordinates for trial are listed below:

```
ulx = -84.53357944492396 # 1
uly = 33.93648279999999  # 2
lrx = -84.53289279941636 # 3
lry = 33.935913117859215 # 4
```

Running `gdalinfo` to confirm CRS:

```
Files: afp6_mosaic_4326.tif
Size is 53083, 64177
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-84.540445928999958,33.936482815000005)
Pixel Size = (0.000000595367895,-0.000000595367895)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -84.5404459,  33.9364828) ( 84d32'25.61"W, 33d56'11.34"N)
Lower Left  ( -84.5404459,  33.8982739) ( 84d32'25.61"W, 33d53'53.79"N)
Upper Right ( -84.5088420,  33.9364828) ( 84d30'31.83"W, 33d56'11.34"N)
Lower Right ( -84.5088420,  33.8982739) ( 84d30'31.83"W, 33d53'53.79"N)
Center      ( -84.5246440,  33.9173784) ( 84d31'28.72"W, 33d55' 2.56"N)
Band 1 Block=53083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=53083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=53083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

From here, I am attempting to use gdal_translate in order to clip a single test image from the mosaic and save it to local disk:

```
gdal_translate -projwin -84.53357944492396 33.93648279999999 -84.53289279941636 33.935913117859215 afp6_mosaic.tif clipped_image.tif
```

But this approach appears to be generating some output that indicates to me my coordinates are off in some way, that I can't figure out:

```
Input file size is 47132, 68666
ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 1.26077e+08 5.38587e+07 0 0 has negative width and/or height.
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I've tried mixing the order of the coordinates in other combinations with the same result. I'm also curious as what the `Input file size is 47312, 68666` here is indicating. It's not the same size as the mosaic image per `gdalinfo`. Is this indicating the size of the new clipped image?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 as well to make sure that the units are being recognized properly.